# How best to implement a rolling Archive that runs without User Intervention

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

In this case I have a custom object that grows by up to 7,000 records a week(but the same issue could apply to any standard object).

I want to have a rolling archive that archives off records that are say over a year old. The archive can be most anything...even as simple as a flat CSV or Text file on something like BOX or DROPBOX. I would prefer this to be "low overhead and cost" like that and not a MYSQL DB etc.

I am envisioning a Scheduled batch APEX that would query for the records to rolloff, write some fields to a text file on Dropbox and then delete them from the Custom Object.

I do NOT want the users to have to run anything themselves e.g. Excel, reports etc.

I have implemented this with Zapier but looking for something all in Salesforce if I can do it.

Thoughts?

Comment: I fear you'd run into severe problems with the allowed outbound data size. Last time I checked it was 3mb of data, which would mean that about 1500 records (well, more depending on how much fields your records have, but mind the overhead) would be the export limit. What about using heroku? (as it's part of salesforce now)

Comment: why not archive them to an Archive__c object in SFDC? Is there a reason the archive has to be outside of sfdc?